# Are there any watch endpoints for the Google Classroom api?

Tags: google-classroom

In the Google Drive API there are "watch" endpoints that allow 3rd parties be notified when there are changes via push notifications.

In particular, I'm trying to keep my service's class roster in sync with Google Classroom, and would like to avoid polling if possible.  Are there any such endpoints in Classroom API, or any other way to be notified without polling?

Comment: For now there are no "watch" endpoints for the Classroom API. I'm not sure if Google will add those endpoint to the API in the future. But for now i think you will have to poll the API to check for any changes.

Comment: Drat - ok.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In September 2017, Google introduced push notifications for roster changes. You can now listen to these notifications to get notified when student/teachers are added/removed from the class roster.

Google 09/2017 update on introducing the feature - 
https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6149237?hl=en

Google Classroom API documentation about Push notifications-
https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications

Answer (score 1):

The Classroom API currently does not offer this feature. You can star [this feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4571) to indicate your interest and be notified if/when it's developed in the future!